# Reference: Ito lemma for rough paths

Tags: stochastic-calculus, rough-paths

Hi I'm looking for an Ito-type lemma for rough paths but am having difficulty finding something.  Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are some results in *A Course on Rough Paths* by Friz and Hairer, have you looked there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Nate Eldredge mentioned, here is a recent paper that you might like to consider.

Keller, Christian; Zhang, Jianfeng *Pathwise Itô calculus for rough paths and rough PDEs with path dependent coefficients*. Stochastic Process. Appl. 126 (2016), no. 3, 735–766.

[This copy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7464) is publicly available at the arXiv.

Comment: This is wonderful.  Thank you to you both!!